# Two questions regarding boundaries and rectifiable curves in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb R^2$, with the usual (euclidean) topology.

**Question 1.**  Let $D$ be an open, bounded subset of $\mathbb R^2$. Is it true that if an open ball meets $D$ and $int(\mathbb R^2\setminus D)$, then it must meet (= have a nonempty intersection with) $\partial D$ ? If so, how do we show it ? If not, can we make additional assumptions about $D$ to make it true ?

I know this looks like a fairly elementary topology question, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Is it somehow related to Jordan's curve theorem ?

**Question 2.**  Let $\gamma$ be a rectifiable curve or, more simply, a piecewise $C^1$ function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R^2$ with finite length $L$. Is it true that $\gamma([0,1])$ meets at most $L+1$ disjoint unit balls ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1

Yes. Let $B$ be the ball that intersects $D$ and $int(D^c)$. Since $B$ is connected, $B$ would not be covered by $D$ and $int(D^c)$, which means there exists at least one point $p\in B$ so that $p\not\in D$ and $p\not\in int(D^c)$. Proving $p$ is then belonging to $\partial D$ is left to you.

Question 2

No. Let $L$ be $1$, and let the centers of the unit ball be $(-1,\sqrt{3}), (1,\sqrt{3})$, and $(0,0)$. Let the curve be the straight line from $(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+0.001)$ to $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+0.001)$, then it intersects 3 unit balls.

Comment: +1..For Q1, the sets $int (D), int (D^c), \partial D$ are pairwise disjoint & their union is $\Bbb R^2.$ If an open ball $B$ intersects  the first 2 but not the 3rd, then $B$ is the union of the 2 non-empty open sets $B\cap int (D), B\cap int (D^c).$ But $B$ is connected......For Q2,  we could also take $\gamma ([0,1])=[0,1]\times \{0\}.$ Let the centers of the balls be $(1/2,1-r), (1-r+1/\sqrt 2,\,r-1/\sqrt 2), ( r-1/\sqrt 2, r-1/\sqrt 2)$ where $r>0$ and $r$ is small enough.... Q: How many pair-wise disjoint open unit balls can intersect  a rectifiable curve of length $1$ in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @Yesfun Yeh Wow ok, thanks. I knew question 1 had to have a simple answer, I always forget about connectedness. As for question 2, what if we consider open squares (with edges parallel to the axes) instead of balls ? I can't seem to find any counter-example... Otherwise, as DanielWainfleet suggested, is there a bound on the number of balls (or squares) it can intersect ? Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Oooh wait no this is stupid. Of course there are counter examples, even with 4 squares. So... maybe hitting 5 squares with a unit length curve is impossible ?

Comment: Hitting 5 squares is impossible for a unit length curve,  since no matter how we arrange these squares, the projection of the squares to the x-axis (or y-axis) will include 3 disjoint unit intervals, which means before projection, the curve meeting all squares will have length greater than 1. (because the projection of the curve has length greater than 1)